# Ultimate Member: do stuff after user login

Tags: wordpress

I would like to trigger some specific actions (custom code) after user login in my WP site.

I use Ultimate Member plugin foe registration/login and, so far, I had no success trying to change the existing code.

Where should I put my code in order to be executed after user login?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this hook will be triggered once use logs in.

```
function your_function() {
  // your code
}
add_action('wp_login', 'your_function');
```

To read more about it -> https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_login